# Изменить аргументы функции при вызове

Tags: python

Есть функция, внутри которой происходят один или несколько вызовов другой функции

```py
def func(app):
    other_func('/test/', app)
    other_func('/test2/', app)
```

Могу ли я при вызове функции `func` изменить аргументы вызываемых ей функций? Например добавить путям префикс.

```py
def discover(app, func, prefix):
    if prefix:
        pass # Тут должна быть логика, которая вызывает func с измененными аргументами
    else:
        func(app)
```

Comment: а почему нельзя передать в `func` и аргументы для внутренних функций или имеется в виду что-то другое?

Comment: @Zhihar да  можно конечно, но таких функций много по коду, это регистрация маршрутов во фласке. Мне хотелось бы передать префикс (номер версии апи) в одном месте когда я вызываю `discover` и добавить префикс сразу всем маршрутам, которые при вызове этого `discover` обрабатываются. А так конечно можно сразу пути с префиксом везде писать, типа `other_func('/v3/test/', app)`

Comment: Так а доступ к чему именно у вас есть и к чему нет из перечисленных функций?

Comment: @CrazyElf ко всему есть, я могу еще аргументов в func передать. Неудобно это просто, т.к. этих функций func много. Альтернативы есть, короче, мне интересно можно ли сдлетаь так как я напиал или это плохой путь

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров Так а вам надо сразу для всех функций префикс менять одновременно, или для части? Если для части, то каким образом определяется/задаётся эта часть?

Comment: @CrazyElf для всех в рамках одного вызова discover.

Comment: @CrazyElf даже так - в моем примере функция одна, вот можем считать что она одна и для нее надо поменять аргументы.

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров Вызовы могут идти параллельно? Если нет, то можно было бы просто глобальную переменную выставлять и её значение добавлять внутри функций к пути. Если параллельно могут вызываться, то надо аналог сессий, видимо, делать

Comment: @CrazyElf сейчас немного поменяю вопрос, чтобы функция тоже передавалась в `discover`

Comment: @CrazyElf поменял, теперь `func` передается в сам `discover`. А на деле у меня список таких функций, который вытаскивается из модуля. То есть в  рамках одного вызова `discover` надо изменить только ту функцию, которая передается внутрь этого `discover`, если есть префикс. А если нет - вызывать как есть.

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров И всё же не понимаю, в чём проблема добавить в `func` параметр с путями и передавать его из `discover` туда

Answer (score 0):

Если функцию определить внутри, то она увидит то что во внешней функции

```
def discover(app, func, prefix):
    prefix = prefix or '/'
    def func(app):
        nonlocal prefix
        other_func(prefix, app) 
    func(app)
```